# unexpected XMLHttpRequest content-length header set by browser (about 15% too large)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Problem: 
  unexpected XMLHttpRequest content-length header set by browser (about 15% too large)
  expected: Content-Length:130533
  got: Content-Length:149830
I don't care about this issue exactly, however my request is being rejected and this is the only funny thing that I can notice.

I'm making an XMLHttpRequest, where I attempt to upload a file from a string as multipart/formdata. I am trying to emulate accessing a website by making cross origin requests (with privileges of a chrome extension).

I'm following this guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript#Using_XMLHttpRequest_and_the_FormData_object

I wrote something like the following snippet (originally used fetch api, but had the same result).

```
const multipart_data = get_multipart_data(); // created using url provided above
console.log("Length is: " + multipart_data.length);

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
  console.log("LOADED!");
});

// Define what happens in case of error
xhr.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
  console.log("ERROR!");
});

// Set up our request
xhr.open('POST', location);

// Add the required HTTP header to handle a multipart form data POST request
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary=' + file.boundary);

// And finally, send our data.
xhr.send(multipart_data);
```

Note that I log the length of my requests body. I also check the content-length header set by chrome, and there is a pretty big discrepency.

Any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: Check your network tab in developer tools, compare what your extension sends with what you send when accessing the web page as usual.

Comment: `expected: Content-Length:130533` - how did you calculate this number? Did you take into consideration the "multipart/form-data boundary" and any additional size due to endcodeURIcomponent for example?

Comment: @Walk
As far as I can tell the requests are identical, except the legitimate request has the content length that I expected.

Comment: @JaromandaX



This takes in to account the "multipart/form-data", etc, it is from data.length, and I use xhr.send(data). I'm not sure what encodeURIcomponent is. Does this mean that my binary data BODY gets url encoded before being sent?

Comment: I'm speculating only

Comment: Have you tried sending it without specifying those headers? If your `multipart_data` is a FormData object browser should set those by itself.

Comment: It would be helpful for you to provide a *complete* [mcve] which duplicates the problem. That way other people could actually try it out and test rather than have to **guess**.

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Without a [mcve], the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to **guess** at significant portions of what your problem might be.